# Error while taking the backup using pg_dump

Tags: postgresql-9.2, pg-dump

We are using postgresql 9.2 version. While taking the backup of the database using pg_dump we are facing below error.

Please guide me how to rectify this issue.

```
pg_dump: [archiver (db)] query was: COPY public.aclappliedtopep (id, instance_version, direction, aclname, ifname, owningentityid, protocolendpoint_id, deploypending, authentityid, authentityclass, accesscontrollist_id) TO stdout;
pg_dump: FATAL:  terminating connection due to administrator command
pg_dump: [archiver (db)] query failed: server closed the connection unexpectedly
                This probably means the server terminated abnormally
                before or while processing the request.
pg_dump: [archiver (db)] query was: COPY public.aclappliedtopep (id, instance_version, direction, aclname, ifname, owningentityid, protocolendpoint_id, deploypending, authentityid, authentityclass, accesscontrollist_id) TO stdout;
pg_dump: [archiver (db)] connection to database "qovr" failed: could not connect to server: Connection refused
                Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
                TCP/IP connections on port 5433?
pg_dump: error reading large object 69417845: FATAL:  terminating connection due to administrator command
FATAL:  terminating connection due to administrator command
pg_dump: could not open large object 59087743: FATAL:  terminating connection due to administrator command
FATAL:  terminating connection due to administrator command
```

Comment: Are you sure your server is listening on localhost 127.0.0.1 and accepting connections on port 5433 and not on the standard port 5432?

Comment: yes its listening the port.